# Trying to make a discord bot but on.message or message.content not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, bots, chatbot

I want the bot to use the gpt-3 API to answer questions but for some reason on.message is not working

```
import openai
import discord


openai.api_key = "apikey"

client = discord.Client()

@client.event

async def on_ready():
 print('online')

async def on_message(message):
   
    if message.content.startswith("!ask"):
        print('I read the message')
        

        question = message.content[5:]

        response = openai.Completion.create(
            engine="text-davinci-002",
            prompt=f"{question}\n",
            temperature=0.7,
            max_tokens=1024,
            top_p=1,
            frequency_penalty=0,
            presence_penalty=0
        )

        await message.channel.send(response.choices[0].text)


client.run('token')
```

Everything works fine and the 'online' appears but after that i don't know what's happening since i am not getting any errors (Sorry if its something obvious i am just now learning)

the

```
client.run('token')
open.api_key="apikey"
```

are obviously replaced with the real ones in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to register an event, you have to put the [client.event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=client%20event#discord.Client.event) decorator on top of the event functions. Your `on_message` function certainly doesn't have one, so just put one on it.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but now the code doesn't go below the if statement is it something similar?

Comment: @panoskava What does that mean? I don't quite understand this question.

Comment: What exactly is wrong? I can't understand just by `it's not working`.

Comment: its simply doesnt do anything at all its not even giving some error its like it doesnt exist...
i tried giving all the permisions nessecery but still nothing..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@client.event` for every event

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
 print('online')

@client.event # <- this is new
async def on_message(message):
   # ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but now the code doesn't go below the if statement is it something similar?